# Java - read message/rfc822 from MultipartFormDataInput

Tags: java, file-upload, mime-types

I have a form for file upload

```
<form id="mydropzone" class="dropzone" style="min-height: 100px" action="/files/uploadFile"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="noteId" th:value="${model.id}" />
</form>
```

`MultipartFormDataInput`. comes from `javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType`

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(value = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Path("/uploadFile")
    @AllowPermission(value = Permission.EDIT_NOTE)
    public Response uploadFileMultipart(MultipartFormDataInput input)
            throws RequestException, IOException {
        System.out.println("theInput " + input);
        FileModel model = convertToFile(input, "file");
        Long noteId = getOptionalParam(input, "noteId");
        model.setNoteId(noteId);
        UploadFileMutation.UploadFile uploadFile = fileService.uploadFile(model);
        if(uploadFile != null){
            return Response.ok(uploadFile).build();
        }else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }

    }
```

the problem come from here  `inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null)` it always return null

```
private FileModel convertToFile(MultipartFormDataInput input,
            String paramName) throws IOException {
        Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
        List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get(paramName);

        for (InputPart inputPart : inputParts) {

            MultivaluedMap<String, String> header = inputPart.getHeaders();
            String fileName = getFileName(header);

            //convert the uploaded file to inputstream
            InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);

            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            FileModel model = new FileModel();
            model.setName(fileName);
            model.setData(bytes);
            return model;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Note this code works just fine with all types except **content-type : message/rfc822**

any hint on how I can convert `.eml` files  to byte[]

I tried this method but I got the same error

```
private byte[] readByteArray(InputPart inputPart) throws Exception {
        Field f = inputPart.getClass().getDeclaredField("bodyPart");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        BodyPart bodyPart = (BodyPart) f.get(inputPart);
        SingleBody body = (SingleBody)bodyPart.getBody();

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        body.writeTo(os);
        byte[] fileBytes = os.toByteArray();
        return fileBytes;
    }
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RestEasy, you might be affected by [this bug](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY-1255).

There is this workaround described by Felix Knecht:

> I worked around the issue by using a CustomMultipartFormDataReader
> which uses a CustomMultipartFormDataInputImpl to parse the
> entityStream. CustomMultipartFormDataInputImpl::BinaryMessage then
> sets a CustomMimeStreamParser which in turn which offers a
> setNoRecurse() method.